# Segmentation Fault, Creating Sockets

Tags: c, sockets, networking

I keep getting a segmentation error when I try and define a socket. Is this an issue related to the code? I have been debugging using print statements but I have not managed to find the problem. Some of the print statements are never run.

**Excerpt from code file**

```
#include<netinet/in.h>
#include<errno.h>
#include<netdb.h>
#include<stdio.h>   //For standard things
#include<stdlib.h>  //malloc
#include<string.h>  //strlen

#include<netinet/ip_icmp.h> //Provides declarations for icmp header
#include<netinet/udp.h> //Provides declarations for udp header
#include<netinet/tcp.h> //Provides declarations for tcp header
#include<netinet/ip.h>  //Provides declarations for ip header
#include<netinet/if_ether.h>    //For ETH_P_ALL
#include<net/ethernet.h>    //For ether_header
#include<sys/socket.h>
#include<arpa/inet.h>
#include<sys/ioctl.h>
#include<sys/time.h>
#include<sys/types.h>
#include<unistd.h>
FILE *logfile = 0;
struct sockaddr_in source,dest;
int tcp=0,udp=0,icmp=0,others=0,igmp=0,total=0,i,j;
int useLog = 0;
int main()
{
    int saddr_size , data_size;
    struct sockaddr saddr;

    unsigned char *buffer = (unsigned char *) malloc(65536); //Its Big!
    if (useLog == 1){
        printf("Using Log File");
        logfile=fopen("log.txt","w");
    }
    if(!logfile)
    {
        printf("Unable to create log.txt file. \n");
    }
    printf("Starting...\n");
    //Create Socket
    printf("Here I Am0");
    int sock_raw = socket( AF_PACKET , SOCK_RAW , htons(ETH_P_ALL)) ;
    //Bind to interface
    printf("Here I Am1");
    setsockopt(sock_raw , SOL_SOCKET , SO_BINDTODEVICE , "wlan0" , strlen("wlan0")+ 1 );
    printf("Here I Am2");
```

**The Expected Output**

The program can create the socket and the additional print statements can be run.

**The Actual Output:**

```
gcc test.c && sudo ./a.out

Unable to create log.txt file.
Starting...
Segmentation fault
```

Any help appreciated.

Comment: Is this complete code?   It reaches till  printf("Here I Am2");. Probably add \n and see. gdb would be best.

Comment: @AvalSarri No this is not the complete code, just the isolated section where I think the problem lies. Can't use gdb due to it not running the code when I do run (segmentation error)  unless I am doing it wrong perhaps?

Comment: In the first place, use `fprintf()` to print your debug messages to `stderr` instead of printing them (by default) to `stdout` via `printf()`.  Or at minimum, include a newline at the end of your debug messages.  Without one of those you cannot have any confidence that the messages printed on the console give a true view of the program's actual progress.

Comment: In the second place, always check the return values of functions that report on errors that way, unless you genuinely do not care whether an error has occurred (rare).  That especially includes functions that open files and devices (`fopen`, `open`, `socket`, ...), and allocation functions such as `malloc`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger socket() returns 3

Comment: Well that's *one* thing to tick off the list.